# Why does commit to mysql in java take so long?

Tags: java, transactions

I am trying to execute the following code in java:

```java
void method(Connection conn) {
  // Make no auto-commits
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);
  // Create a savepoint just in case of rollback
  Savepoint point = conn.setSavepoint();

  try {
    // Do something with database
  } catch (Exception e) {    
    System.out.println("[ERROR] Something went wrong, so rolling back...");
    conn.rollback(point);
    return;
  }

  // If everything ok, do the commit
  System.out.println("[INFO] Everything OK...");
  conn.commit(); // The problem line
}
```

Now, the problem is the last line - all the queries to the database inside **try** block work fine, but the commit seems to make a pause - it stops the program, and that's all. What could possibly cause the delay for the transaction commit?

The interesting thing is, that my colleague seems to run my code fine on his machine (we both have Java 6 installed), so what could possibly be wrong on my machine?

'''UPDATE'''. Turns out this is not the mysql problem, there is a problem with instantianting connection before the call of this method. So the question should be closed, I guess

Comment: I would look to see how long it take to commit data on your MySQL. Try doing the same SQL via another means like a GUI.

Comment: i guess the cause of the delay is some where else than in this method. to ensure this, just setAutoCommit(true), and remove the commit part, then check if it changes any thing!, else we need the code part where you call this method!

Comment: Is it a remote DB or on the same machine?

Comment: Fildor, it's on the same machine

Comment: What happens if you DON'T create a save point? The only reason why I would otherwise see a transaction taking a long time to commit (besides a slow network connection) is when the transaction is in fact huge with lots of changes.